# Determine if a type is convertible to IDictionary<string, object>, where Key can be any type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, type-conversion

Let's say we have a type that implements `IDictionary<string, string>`. It's called `MyStringDictionary`.

I'm doing some property/field/method reflection and would like to know if the member is a type that I can convert to an `IDictionary<string, object>`.

I know that `typeof(IDictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyStringDictionary))` will be true since both generic parameters match. However, I won't be doing direct assignment to `<string, string>` but instead will be converting to `<string, object>`, something like this:

```
public class MyStringDictionary : IDictionary<string, string> {
   // Notice that the class itself has no generic type arguments!
}

MyStringDictionary myStringDict = GetBigDictionary();
IDictionary<string, object> genericDict = myStringDict
   .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (object) kvp.Value);
```

How can I determine that this conversion is possible?

I was thinking that I can look to see if it implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>`, but again I'm stymied by the fact that I don't know the type argument of the `Value`, and don't need to know it because it will just be boxed to `object`.

Comment: Wow, -1 already, like 0.2 seconds after posting!?!?!

Comment: @GrantWinney I never even had a chance to see the "0": upon submission, it already had a -1. If it was you who voted me up, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking that I can look to see if it implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>`

Absolutely, that's the way to go! Now for the details of *how* this can be done: go through results of `myObj.GetType().GetInterfaces()`, and call the method below. If you get `true` back, second and third parameters would be set to the type of key and the type of value.

```
private static bool IsEnumKvp(Type t, out Type k, out Type v) {
    k = v = null;
    if (!t.IsGenericType) return false;
    var genDef = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    if (genDef != typeof(IEnumerable<>)) return false;
    var itemType = t.GenericTypeArguments[0];
    if (!itemType.isGenericType) return false;
    var genItemDef = itemType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    if (genItemDef != typeof(KeyValuePair<,>)) return false;
    var kvpTypeArgs = genItemDef.GenericTypeArguments;
    k = kvpTypeArgs[0];
    v = kvpTypeArgs[1];
    return true;
}
```

Calling this method on `MyStringDictionary` should produce a `true`:

```
foreach (var t : MyStringDictionary.GetType().GetInterfaces()) {
    Type keyType, valType;
    if (IsEnumKvp(t, out keyType, out valType)) {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Your class implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<{0},{1}>>"
        ,   keyType.FullName
        ,   valType.FullName
        );
    }
}
```

Note that potentially this method could return `true` multiple types.

Comment: I had *just* hit on `GetInterfaces` two minutes ago and was puzzling my way through `GetGenericTypeDefinition` but got stuck on `typeof(IDictionary<,>)`... Oh, not `is` but `==` since we're dealing with `Type` objects not instances of those types.

Comment: So your answer can probably be simplified with `IDictionary<,>` directly instead of checking `IEnumerable<>` and then `KeyValuePair<,>`, right?

Comment: @ErikE Using `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>` is more general, because each dictionary is ienumerable, but not each ienumerable is also a dictionary.

Comment: Well, the difference is that the `IDictionary<,>` is guaranteed to not have duplicate `Key`s but the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>` is not.

Comment: @ErikE That is true too: you don't need to bother with `GroupBy` on the key if you know that your input is an `IDictionary`.

Comment: Answer selected because you used `GetInterfaces` and all the right pieces, with the note that just directly checking `IDictionary<,>` and the first `GenericTypeArgument` is all that's needed.